# Req.body coming up empty

Tags: node.js, httprequest

I know this question has been asked multiple times but I wanted to know how to use req.body in this particular case as I can't figure out for my life where to put app.use(body-parser).

I have a router service,

```
const {FileUtillities} = require('hex-utilities');

class TransactionRouter {
  constructor(service) {
    service.addRouter(this);
  }
router() {
    const router = this.Router();
    router.post('/transaction', this.postTransaction.bind(this));
    return router;
  }
  postTransaction(req, res) {
    const amount = req.body.amount;
    const fromAccount = req.body.fromAccount;
    const toAccount = req.body.toAccount;
    return this.service.sendTransaction(fromAccount, toAccount, amount, res);
  }
}
module.exports = TransactionRouter;
```

My req.body here comes up `{}`. How to solve this issue?

Comment: in your server file

Comment: @ShubhamTiwari can I not use server file and change something in this file?

Comment: which ever is your entry file specified in your packge.json ,you can modify that file according to your need . and that is also known as your server or entry file

Comment: what to add in that file?

Comment: the stuff you mentioned in you question   **particular case as I can't figure out for my life where to put app.use(body-parser).**

Comment: just put **app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));**
**app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));** just below where you finished requirng your modules in your server file

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like:

`router.post('/transaction', bodyParser.json(), this.postTransaction.bind(this));`

Ideally, this should be done at place where you have created instance of an express app like: `var app = express();` and pass bodyparser middleware to app using `app.use(bodyParser.json())`

Answer (score -1):

Two options come to mind:

Before handling the route, or in lining it:

```
const {FileUtillities} = require('hex-utilities');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

class TransactionRouter {
  constructor(service) {
    service.addRouter(this);
  }
router() {
    const router = this.Router();
    // here is good
    router.use(bodyParser.json())
    // or inline
    router.post('/transaction', bodyParser.json(), this.postTransaction.bind(this));
    // router.post('/transaction', this.postTransaction.bind(this));
    return router;
  }
  postTransaction(req, res) {
    const amount = req.body.amount;
    const fromAccount = req.body.fromAccount;
    const toAccount = req.body.toAccount;
    return this.service.sendTransaction(fromAccount, toAccount, amount, res);
  }
}
module.exports = TransactionRouter;
```

Comment: body parser should be defined in entry file, not for every route

Comment: He asked it in the file, look at the comment in OP's question... @ShubhamTiwari That is not true, if you need specific routes to handle multi part data or other types that body parser does not support, you have to do it on router/handler level.

Comment: sir every req  in js  always in JSON so ,it is always recomended with app.use because it will be applied to every incoming request. and multipart req and other type  of req are applicable only for some routes in most cases, if it is applicable for all routes, we will also define that in app.use,